# Try Catch blocks within a Custom Controller?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, try-catch

I have a VF page which is fired based on a custom button click from Case record's detail page. `window.location = 'apex/onClickPage?Id={!Case.Id}';`

In Apex controller class, I am getting the Id from the URL using: `String caseUrlId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');`

Based on the URL, I am querying Case object to get some field that are to be displayed on the VF page.

If a user deletes the Id from the URL, I am getting a page with error message: `common.apex.runtime.impl.ExecutionException: Attempt to de-reference a null object`. 
How can I use Try-Catch blocks to handle this:

> If Id from the URL is deleted, I need to redirect the user to the Standard Salesforce Home page.

Comment: Do you have a code sample? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3):

You can also just validate the Id parameter. There are a number of different ways. Here's one example. You can use this in a utility class.

For instance you can check if it's not null, if is an Id, if is the correct SObject type, and if it returns a query result. If this is false, redirect them.

Additional checks can be added for accessibility and even if the Id is the correct record type.

```
public static Boolean isValidParamId(String paramId, SObjectType soType) {
    Boolean isValid = false;
    if (paramId != null && paramId InstanceOf Id && ((Id)paramId).getSobjectType() == soType) {
        String soName = soType.getDescribe().getName();
        SObject[] records = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + soName + ' WHERE Id = :paramId');
        isValid = !records.isEmpty() ? true : false;
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

If you are using the case SObject, you can use this as so.

```
isValidParamId(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'), Case.SObjectType);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using standardController then you can use controller.getRecord() no SOQL needed. You can try this

```
public class testCase{
String caseUrlId;
public testCase(){
 caseUrlId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
 try{
 // caseUrlId<> NULL && caseUrlId <> '' can be added to if you want null check
 if(Id.valueOf(caseUrlId)){
   // your SOQL here.
 }
}
catch(Exception E){
// Exception handeling here
}

}

}
```

As you want to with try catch I showed in this way. You can use regEX and Id.getSObjectType() as well to check the object type. reference [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm)